# Do I use Combination or Permutation?

Tags: permutations, combinations

I've been having trouble figuring out the right equation to use on this problem. Help?

"Given two integers, M and N, compute the number of ways it is possible to choose M marbles from a set of N marbles."

Comment: Hint: **choose**

Comment: What would you recommend? I haven't looked at either in a few years.

Comment: As I said. **choose**

Comment: Let's do permutation then.

Comment: No. Have you heard something like "5 choose 3"? If not, google that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's combinations.  The number of ways to choose $M$ marbles from $N$ marbles is ${N \choose M}$ (read "N choose M").  This binomial coefficient is equal to $\frac{N!}{M! (N-M)!}$, which is the coefficient of $x^M y^{N-M}$ in the expansion of $(x+y)^N$.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, Permutations are used for arranging (order matters) and combinations are for choosing (order doesn't matter).
So you should use combinations: $\begin{pmatrix}N\\M\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 0):

Unless they mention something about the order in which the marbles are chosen, this is a combination problem. It is asking you to determine the number of ways you can choose $M$ marbles from a set of $N$ marbles (assuming $N$ is greater than $M$ otherwise this doesn't make sense).

So as you know this is an application of the formula $\binom {N} {M}$

Comment: would the downvoter care to elaborate on the reason for their downvote?